# When does the garbage collector run when calling Haskell exports from C?

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, ghc, ffi

When exporting a Haskell function to be called from C, when does Haskell's garbage get collected? If C owns `main` then there is no way to predict the next call in to Haskell. This question is especially pertinent when running single-threaded Haskell or without parallel GC.

Comment: If you're worried about a specific foreign export or exports you could add a [`performGC`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/System-Mem.html#v:performGC) before returning the `Addr`.

Comment: @Cirdec What `Addr`?

Comment: IIRC, garbage collection gets a chance to run every time Haskell code allocates something. If your program frequently calls into Haskell, this should be enough. Otherwise, if you worry about Haskell retaining memory for too much time, you can trigger a GC calling `performGC` from C.

Comment: @chi If you confirm that "IIRC" then this is the answer!

Comment: I second what chi says about the GC, I've learned the same, however I'm not sure how it answers the GC's ability to predict anything. How would the runtime know that a value will not be needed again from the C side?

Comment: @MasterMastic The same way it knows when it's no longer needed from the Haskell side, when there are no more GC roots from which it is reachable. The two most interesting [basic foreign types](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch8.html#x15-1560008.4.2) are [`FunPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Ptr.html#t:FunPtr) and [`StablePtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-StablePtr.html#t:StablePtr). When you make a `StablePtr` or `FunPtr` new GC roots are created that exist until they are freed.

Comment: @MasterMastic Roughly, when you pass something from Haskell to C, you have to "pin" that data so that it will not be freed by GC. After you know C no longer needs it, you can unpin it. It's manual and not so convenient, but in C we are used to manual memory management after all, so it's not so terrible if we also have to do that at the boundary of the two languages.

Comment: @3noch I'm not confident enough to write an actual answer. I read something in the far past about the GHC runtime, but I'm not an expert about it.

Comment: A downvote? I'm all ears for how to improve my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you initialize the `ghc` runtime, you can pass rts flags to it via argc and argv [like so](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html#using-own-main):

```
  RtsConfig conf = defaultRtsConfig;
  conf.rts_opts_enabled = RtsOptsAll;
  hs_init_ghc(&argc, &argv, conf);
```

This lets you [set options](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html#rts-options-gc) to, for example fix a smaller maximum heap size or use a compaction algorithm on the nursery to further reduce allocation. Further, note there is an idle GC whose interval can be set (or disabled), and if you link the threaded runtime, that should run whether or not you ever yield back to a Haskell call.

**Edit**: I haven't actually performed experimentation to verify the following, but if we look at the [source of hs_init_ghc](http://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/blob/685398ebc5c8377597714cd8c3e97439d32e3a02:/rts/RtsStartup.c#l99) we see that it initializes signal handlers, which should include the [timer handlers](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Signals) that respond on `SIGVTALRM` and indeed it also starts the time, which calls (on POSIX) [`timer_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) that should throw those signals on regular intervals. In turn, this periodically should "wake up" the RTS whether or not anything is happening, which in turn should mean that it will run idle GC whether or not the system yields back to Haskell from C. But again, I have only read the code and commentary, not tested this myself.

Comment: You seem to be on an "answer old questions" kick. Any particular reason, or are you just in the mood?

Comment: @dfeuer insomnia and an occasional compulsion that overtakes me to try to drive down our unanswered questions ratio.

Comment: @sclv I'm almost ready to accept this answer, but the meat of my question still remains: when doe the GC actually run? Is it just "when there are allocations" on the Haskell side or something?

Comment: @sclv Great! Thank you.